# How do you conditionally update a table based on the current year? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently doing a school project in which we need to create a database for a real estate management company. I have about 14 tables but only these two are relevant for my question: `BUILDING`and `TaxRates`.

It is requested to have the taxes (in $) for the year, for each building. The taxes are calculated based on the rates in the `TaxRates`table and the landValue in the `Building` table. New values are added each year and historic rates are kept as well.

How can I update the taxes in the `Building`table so that the amount shown takes the current year into consideration, as well as the city?

I'm guessing I have to start off like this, but I'm not sure what to do next and how to take the current year into account.

```
UPDATE Building
SET taxes =
CASE WHEN
```

```
CREATE TABLE Building (
    buildingID          NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    addressID           NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
    qtyUnits            NUMBER (3) NOT NULL,
    landValue           NUMBER (15) NOT NULL,
    purchasePrice       NUMBER (15) NOT NULL
    taxes               NUMBER (15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TaxRates (
    taxID          NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city           VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    taxRate        NUMBER (3) NOT NULL,
    year           NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
);
```

**EDIT:** Actually there is one more table that matters. The `AddressDetails`table. The tax rate varies depending on the city.

````
CREATE TABLE AdressDetails (
    addressID   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    streetNo    Number (10) NOT NULL,
    streetName  VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    postalCode  VARCHAR2 (6) NOT NULL Check
    city        VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
    province    VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
    buildingID  NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
)```
````

Comment: You should tell us what's the join condition between the tables correctly and not make us figure out ourselves. Your design also looks suspicious to me for eg What's  `buildingID` doing in `AdressDetails` ?  Also, add some sample rows from each relevant table so that it becomes easier to simulate it and provide you a solution that's closer to your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data for each building with amount of tax for a particular year you will need another table with columns building, tax paid and year.

So taxes column will vanish from your building table and new table building_tax will have foreign keys to building and tax tables

Another thing to consider is if the land value will change every year and will be part of tax calculation??

Comment: The taxes displayed in the `Building` table are for the current year. For the purpose of this project we do not need to keep historic value, or historic taxes in $. All we need is a table with the historic tax rates. I know it doesn't make much sense, but this is what's requested.  
**EDIT:** Basically I want the taxes column to update based on the tax rate and the land value, but the tax rate has to be fetched from the tax rate table by validating the year column matches the current year.

Comment: One of the possibility is to write a trigger on tax table, after every insert go to building table and set new calculated tax value.